# Laravel: How to check if route contains nothing after a slash

Tags: laravel

I have a condition to check what URL it is so I can set a proper tab class to be active.
I have code

```
`{{ Request::is('popular') || Request::is('/') || Request::is('category/*/popular') || Request::is('category/*') ? 'nav-active' : '' }}`
```

The last condition is wrong, for example when the URL is `http://localhost:8000/category/goodwin/new` that will still be correct, which I don't want. How can I write a condition to check if there is anything after `category` but only after one `/`

P.S. I have other conditions for `new` and `top posts` which work correctly

Comment: Share all possible condition, why not `if (!Request::is('/*'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `url()->current()` and then do string analysis on that. E.g. with preg_match and a regex, or by simply counting the number of slashes.

Example:

```
preg_match("/(.*)\/category\/(.*)\/(?!popular)(.*)/", url()->current());
```

The regex `(.*)\/category\/(.*)\/(?!popular)(.*)` checks whether the URL matches `.../category/*/*` except where the final `*` is `popular`.

That would allow you to do:

```
{{ (Request::is('popular') || 
   Request::is('/') || 
   Request::is('category/*/popular') || 
   Request::is('category/*')) &&
   preg_match("/(.*)\/category\/(.*)\/(?!popular)(.*)/", url()->current()) == 0
   ? 'nav-active' : '' }}
```

I would consider moving away from the ternary operator as this is getting quite bulky. You should probably also put this logic in the controller and just pass a variable to the view.